# How can I visualize the values of a matrix in 3d with Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, 3d

In Matlab, I have a matrix `M` with values `M(i,j)`. Each `M(i,j)` represents the height at the coordinates `(i,j)`. I would like to visualize this landscape.

How can I visualize in 3d the plot with axes `(i,j,M(i,j))` ?

Comment: `surf(M)` does the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for example:

```
mesh(M)
%or
meshc(M)
%or
bar3(M)
```

and others.